# How can I put the desired value into an array by comparing the object values?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have selectedPlaces and selectedtags objects.

Also

```
Atemp.tags.[0].tagId,
Ahum.tags.[0].tagId,
Agrouwntemp.tags.[0].tagId is A,B,C,D.
```

I want to put the desired values ​​in an array called datas every time I run answerfunc.

For example, when selectedPlaces.A : true and selectedtags.temp :true; datas contains

```
   [Atemp.tags.[0].tagId, Ahum.tags.[0].tagId, Btemp.tags. [0].tagId, Bhum.tags.[0].tagId] must be entered.
```

But using my code is too inefficient.

How can i fix my code??

```
    selectedPlaces = {
        A: false,
        B: false,
        C: false,
        D: false,
    }

    selectedtags = {
        temp: false,
        hum: false,
        gndTemp: false
    }

    Atemp.tags.[0].tagId, 
    Ahum.tags.[0].tagId, 
    Agrouwntemp.tags.[0].tagId

    Btemp.tags.[0].tagId,
    Bhum.tags.[0].tagId, 
    Bgrouwntemp.tags.[0].tagId

    Ctemp.tags.[0].tagId, 
    Chum.tags.[0].tagId, 
    Cgrouwntemp.tags.[0].tagId

    Dtemp.tags.[0].tagId, 
    Dhum.tags.[0].tagId, 
    Dgrouwntemp.tags.[0].tagId

    let datas = []

    const answerfunc = () => {


    }

    // expected answer = 

    // if selectedPlaces.A : true, selectedtags.temp :true;

    // datas = [Atemp.tags.[0].tagId, Ahum.tags.[0].tagId, Btemp.tags.[0].tagId, Bhum.tags.[0].tagId]    
    // ===     
    // datas = [1,2,3,4]


    // if selectedPlaces.A : true, selectedPlaces.B : true, selectedtags.temp :true; selectedtags.hum :true;


    // datas = [Atemp.tags.[0].tagId ]    
    // ===  
    // datas= [1]
```

I made my code But using my code is too inefficient.

If I were to use this code, it would be hundreds of lines of code. How can I reduce duplication and make my code more efficient?

```
   // const answerfunc = () => {
      let data = []
    // if (selectedPlaces.A && !selectedPlaces.B && !selectedPlaces.C && !selectedPlaces.D && 
      selectedtags) {
    //     datas.push(Atemp.tags.[0].tagId)
    // }

    // .....
    //  }
```

Comment: I suggest stepping back from your current task and going through a few basic JavaScript tutorials. The vast majority of the code in the question does absolutely nothing. :-) [Assuming that A) `Atemp`, `Ahum`, `Agrouwntemp`, and such are declared; if they aren't, it throws a ReferenceError. and B) That there are no accessor properties involved.] Those sequences of property accesses feeding into the comma operator (`Atemp?.tags?.[0].tagId, Ahum?.tags?.[0].tagId, ___`) and so on read the value of the properties in question, then (because nothing uses the result of the comma operator), ...

Comment: ... completely throws the final value away. That isn't (for instance) how you create properties, or declare them (largely, properties don't need declaration), or similar.